# How to implement API like YQL in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, yql

I want to create an API like YQL in PHP where user can run query to fetch data. Can any body please guide me how to achieve this? We can just start from a very basic query. Just need guidance how to achieve this in PHP and MYsql?

Answer (score -1):

I copied and paste this here for you to understand better and those who will view it you take it as a sample approach for your question.

**this is mysql like command for yql**

**

```
select * from html where url="http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=yhoo" and
      xpath='//div[@id="yfi_headlines"]/div[2]/ul/li/a'
```

**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <query xmlns:yahoo="http://www.yahooapis.com/v1/base.rng"
        yahoo:count="15" yahoo:created="2016-01-11T17:09:07Z" yahoo:lang="en-US">
        <diagnostics>
            <publiclyCallable>true</publiclyCallable>
            <url execution-start-time="1" execution-stop-time="1228" execution-time="1227"><![CDATA[http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=yhoo]]></url>
            <url execution-start-time="1" execution-stop-time="1228" execution-time="1227"><![CDATA[http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=yhoo]]></url>
            <user-time>1231</user-time>
            <service-time>2445</service-time>
            <build-version>0.2.369</build-version>
        </diagnostics> 
        <results>
            <a data-ylk="cp:American City Business Journals;o:e;" href="http://us.rd.yahoo.com/finance/external/bizj/SIG=139c9j4lb/*http://www.bizjournals.com/sanjose/news/2016/01/11/yahoo-staff-are-losing-faith-in-the-company-and.html?ana=yahoo">Yahoo staff are losing faith in the company and its leadership</a>
            <a data-ylk="cp:Zacks;o:i;" href="http://finance.yahoo.com/news/technology-stock-roundup-dismal-start-150703080.html">Technology Stock Roundup: Dismal Start to 2016</a>
            <a data-ylk="cp:Forbes;o:e;" href="http://us.rd.yahoo.com/finance/external/forbes/SIG=14082so2n/*http://www.forbes.com/sites/ericjackson/2016/01/11/want-an-instant-2-5-million-bonus-at-yahoo-allegedly-just-threaten-to-quit/?utm_campaign=yahootix&amp;partner=yahootix">Want An Instant $2.5 Million Bonus At Yahoo? Allegedly, Just Threaten To Quit</a>
            <a data-ylk="cp:Barrons.com;o:e;" href="http://us.rd.yahoo.com/finance/external/barrons/SIG=13cgi999q/*http://blogs.barrons.com/techtraderdaily/2016/01/11/yahoo-talk-of-core-sale-in-focus-again-on-nyt-article/?mod=yahoobarrons&amp;ru=yahoo">Yahoo! Talk of 'Core' Sale in Focus Again on NYT Article</a>
            <a data-ylk="cp:Insider Monkey;o:e;" href="http://us.rd.yahoo.com/finance/external/xinsidermonkey/SIG=14d3lit34/*http://www.insidermonkey.com/blog/a-look-at-whitebox-advisors-top-equity-holdings-as-it-prepares-to-close-down-its-mutual-fund-unit-405548/">A Look At Whitebox Advisors Top Equity Holdings As It Prepares To Close Down Its Mutual Fund Unit</a>
            <a data-ylk="cp:Bloomberg;o:i;" href="http://finance.yahoo.com/video/yahoo-said-reconsider-business-sale-142447099.html">Yahoo Said to Reconsider Web Business Sale, Why?</a>
            <a data-ylk="cp:Bloomberg;o:e;" href="http://us.rd.yahoo.com/finance/external/bloomberg/SIG=131lr1djm/*http://www.bloomberg.com/news/videos/2016-01-11/yahoo-said-to-reconsider-web-business-sale-why-?cmpid=yhoo.headline">Yahoo Said to Reconsider Web Business Sale, Why?</a>
            <a data-ylk="cp:CNBC;o:i;" href="http://finance.yahoo.com/video/twitter-shares-down-48-past-134500309.html">Twitter shares down 48% in past year</a>
            <a data-ylk="cp:CNBC;o:e;" href="http://us.rd.yahoo.com/finance/external/cnbc/SIG=112isi8k7/*http://www.cnbc.com/id/103294156?__source=yahoo%7cfinance%7cheadline%7cheadline%7cstory&amp;par=yahoo&amp;doc=103294156">Early movers: BXLT, AEO, HSY, M, APOL, WSM &amp; more</a>
            <a data-ylk="cp:Benzinga;o:i;" href="http://finance.yahoo.com/news/bob-peck-yahoo-separation-bulk-123554615.html">Bob Peck On Yahoo: Separation Is Bulk Of Value</a>
            <a data-ylk="cp:Fox Business Video;o:i;" href="http://finance.yahoo.com/video/time-marissa-mayer-yahoo-ceo-120443101.html">Time for Marissa Mayer to go as Yahoo CEO?</a>
            <a data-ylk="cp:The Wall Street Journal;o:e;" href="http://us.rd.yahoo.com/finance/external/wsj/SIG=134mdgf4d/*http://www.wsj.com/articles/cmo-today-apple-news-falls-short-of-publishers-expectations-1452513606?mod=yahoo_hs">CMO Today: Apple News Falls Short of Publishers' Expectations</a>
            <a data-ylk="cp:Quartz;o:i;" href="http://us.rd.yahoo.com/finance/external/quartz/SIG=12kug5d3h/*http://qz.com/590363/yahoos-plan-a-b-c-d-and-e-for-appeasing-frustrated-investors/?utm_source=YPL">Yahoo’s plan A, B, C, D, and E for appeasing frustrated investors</a>
            <a data-ylk="cp:Bloomberg;o:e;" href="http://us.rd.yahoo.com/finance/external/bloomberg/SIG=136qrbvv6/*http://www.bloomberg.com/news/videos/2016-01-09/yahoo-s-web-business-bloomberg-west-full-show-01-08-?cmpid=yhoo.headline">Yahoo's Web Business: Bloomberg West (Full Show 01/08)</a>
            <a data-ylk="cp:Bloomberg;o:i;" href="http://finance.yahoo.com/video/yahoo-considering-sale-core-biz-234206699.html">Yahoo Considering Sale of Core Biz After Activists’ Push</a>
        </results>
    </query>
```

Visit [this link](https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/guide/two-minute-tutorial.html) for better understanding.